# Shopify - Cannot get custom cart field to show in order note_attributes

Tags: html, shopify

I've tried many different ways, and nothing seems to add my custom field on my cart to the cart attributes like everywhere says you can. I don't understand. I've even used Shopify's UI generator and THAT's not working either. Here is the code I add:

```
<p class="cart-attribute__field">
    <label for="your-name">Your name</label>
    <textarea required class="required" id="your-name" name="attributes[Your name]">{{ cart.attributes["Your name"] }}</textarea>
</p>
```

Then I've tried this:

```
<div style="width:300px; clear:both;">
  <p>
    <label for="delivery_date">Pick a delivery date:</label>
    <input required class="required" id="delivery_date" type="text" name="attributes[delivery_date]" value="{{ cart.attributes.delivery_date }}" />
    <span style="display:block" class="instructions"> We do not deliver during the weekend.</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

That doesn't work either, it has something to do with the `attributes` but I can't figure out what.

Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

If you've pasted your code inside the `<form>...</form>` tags then the issue I see with your code is that setting the value is wrong:

```
<div style="width:300px; clear:both;">
  <p>
    <label for="delivery_date">Pick a delivery date:</label>
    <input required class="required" id="delivery_date" type="date" name="attributes[delivery_date]" value="{{ cart.attributes["delivery_date"] }}" />
    <span style="display:block" class="instructions"> We do not deliver during the weekend.</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

You can see this working at a development store:  https://kotn-eu.myshopify.com pwd skufom

Comment: There's no functional difference between `{{ cart.attributes.delivery_date }}` and `cart.attributes['delivery_date'] }}` - both are valid syntax.

I think the issue is that the OP either doesn't have the code inside the cart form or that the form has a hyperlink to "/checkout" rather than a submit button with a name="checkout" - either of those would prevent the data from being posted to Shopify

Comment: @DaveB I agree there shouldn't be but I have had odd effects enough times that I am still surprised when the cleaner syntax works. I also agree the most likely reason is placement but the OP has never verified either of these so who knows.

Answer (score -1):

In the liquid cart section, inside `<form>` tag you should add `input` or `textarea` with name attribute `note`.

For example:

```
...
<form action="/cart" method="post" novalidate>
...
    <textarea name="note">{{ cart.note }}</textarea>
...
</form>
```

Comment: The poster was asking specifically about cart attributes, which is not the same as the cart note.  Presumably they would be using the note field for something else already.